# Adding jobs to Sidekiq via Rails 4.2 ActiveJob, but jobs never run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I am new to rails. I'm trying to get a basic image_resize job running via Active Job, using Rails 4.2 and Ruby 2.1.5.

I tried to copy the code from here:

```
http://ryanselk.com/2014/09/25/using-background-jobs-in-rails-42-with-active-job/
```

I've got this job:

```
class ResizeImage < ActiveJob::Base
  # Set the Queue as Default
  queue_as :default 

  def perform(img_url)
    puts " in ResizeImage "
    puts img_url

    # Open the image into memory
    image = MiniMagick::Image.open(img_url)

    # Change the image size
    image.resize "100x100"

    puts output_path

    # Write the resulting image
    image.write output_path(img_url)
  end
end
```

and I created this rake task:

```
namespace :simple do

  # call from command line:
  # rake simple:resize_images 

  desc "Resize images"
  task resize_images: :environment do

    Dir.foreach('storage') do |next_image|
      puts next_image
      next if next_image == '.' or next_image == '..'
      ResizeImage.perform_later next_image
    end

  end

end
```

and I set up a folder full of images, and when I run the task, this line:

```
puts next_image
```

prints out all the images in the folder. So that part works.

But none of the "puts" in the job ever run. I feel like it never happens.

I've got redis running on the default port, and I've got the sidekiq gem installed. What am I missing?

I guess I'm wondering, how do I know if the worker died, or if I just called it incorrectly? How do I debug this?

[UPDATE] Okay, so I found this file:

```
cat  /Users/charryDownloads/redis-2.6.17/dump.rdb
```

and it is full of jobs:

```
                            ActiveJob::Q@$Adapters::Sidekiq?::   #Wrapper >arg =[{"job_?K
ResizeImage "@id becede7f4-80cd-4286-be1b-76c94eec8d0c /`?_nam??   iument@n"zachitn_phpxuQqNP.jpg"]}] n`kdafc7cd1e302537    `2aaba@?en`ad_at":1426872747.5798872}?AA2{"retry":true,"queue":"default","class 

                     ActiveJob::Q@$Adapters::Sidekiq?:: #Wrapper >arg   =[{"job_?K
ResizeImage "@id bc28303d5-0923-421e-b8ab-fd115513114c /`?_nam?? iument@n"zachitn_phpEXbfmp.jpg"]}] n`kd23ba182e3d0c17eb557ec32 _en`ad_at":1426872747.579301}?AA6{"retry":true,"queue":"default","class
```

but I see nothing being processed. No work, no output. I assume something is broken with the code in the worker, but how do I find that?

Comment: No error, but no puts, I'm wondering if it doesn't output to standard out?

Comment: I guess it is a separate process, so it won't write to terminal. so there must be a log?

Comment: Did you start the actual sidekiq process? `bundle exec sidekiq`

Comment: Ah, thanks Matt. I ran that and suddenly a huge amount of stuff happened in my terminal. I assume Sidekiq pulled everything that had built up in Redis and ran the jobs.